# Sending on behalf of a user in Outlook fails with permissions error

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, exchange-2010

I get the following deliverable message when trying to send using another accounts email address:

> You can't send a message on behalf of this user unless you have permission to do so. Please make sure you're sending on behalf of the correct sender, or request the necessary permission. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

The account has `Full Access` and `Send As` permissions in Exchange 2010. Deleting the address from the `From:` field (clicking the black cross), redownloading the GAL or deleting the `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Offline Address Books` folder all fix the problem, but only for one email. After the first email is sent successfully I then continue to get the above message again.

Turning off `Cached Exchange Mode` also fixes the problem, but I want that on.  Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: I assume you have updated the GAL correct?  It appears the file that handles these rights [is generated once per day](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/61285622-b387-4e00-bc47-066f1754be50/exchange-cached-mode-and-gal-updates?forum=exchange2010)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one of two things happening here, Firstly make sure that there is no entry for this mail address in the auto complete.

You can check this by typing the email address in the From field, If it is listed here it will display... when its highlighted hit the Del key to remove the entry. Possible not your issue but worth checking if you've emailed them before.

Secondly, ensure that the address you are trying to send from is selected from the Global Address list, so click on the From button and then locate the mail contact from the GAL... I've found that typing the address in manually can do this most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, one of my user was getting this message when he was trying to send a message to a distribution list that he had created in his local address book. He started getting this error when he was sending message to this distribution list after he was migrated from Exchange 2003 to Exchange  2010. So, i just updated the distribution list by double updating the email addressess on the contacts that i could not open. Even selecting the option no worked once i clicked no the address would open fine next time.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this, but if anyone else stumbles over this question, the answer is simple. 'Send As' and 'Send on Behalf' are different permissions. One does not give the other. In this example, 'Send As' has been granted but the user is trying to 'Send on Behalf', and as per the error message that will not work.

Answer (score -1):

If you have provided full access permission on the user mailbox but are still having the problem, check that the user is available in GAL. If not present, check user properties and uncheck `hide user` from the exchange address list.